# How to solve "PICKED UP JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS..." on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have searched for the answer to this question throughout the internet, and after mixing a linux solution and a Google Developers tutorial, finally found the answer. I hope to help everyone that bumps into the same.

[Ubuntu issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650548/remove-annoying-environment-variable-java-tool-options)

[Android Developers tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)

And the answer is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android Studio, go to Help -> Edit custom VM properties

If it isn't created yet, now is the time.
A tab named studio64.exe.vmoptions or studio.exe.vmoptions will open on your IDE and you must add the following:

```
-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

Save and re-run.
All done :D